# How to store string array (which is converted from array list <string> to string array) in shared preference.?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, sharedpreferences, onactivityresult

I Have two activities. I am passing array list from second activity to first activity. In first activity convert array list to string array. now i want to save this string array with shared preference but i can't do that.

second activity code to pass array list

```
                Intent i = new Intent();
                //Bundle extra = new Bundle();
                //i.putStringArrayList("array",h);
                i.putStringArrayListExtra("array", h);
                //i.putExtras(extra);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
                finish();
```

First activity code to get this result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{

if(requestCode == 1){

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File imgFile = null;
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        a= extras.getStringArrayList("array");
        try{
        al = new String[a.size()];
        al = a.toArray(al);

        //for(String ss : al)             
              for(int i = 0; i < al.length; i++){
                  imagepathb.append(al[i]).append(",");

              } 
         }
         sharedpreferences.edit().putString("imgpath",imagepathb.tostring()).commit();                            catch(Exception e){

                  }

        if(ab != null){
            ab =  sharedpreferences.getString("imgpath", ab);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is ab image path : "+ ab, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
        }


    }

   }
}
```

i have trouble by using this code, because when i am trying this code, execution start for only first syntax other two syntax remain as it is and Toast display null value. Also shared preference can not save  value of String-Builder variable `imagepathb`.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < al.length; i++){

     imagepathb.append(al[i]).append(",");
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is image path : "+ imagepathb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
     sharedpreferences.edit().putString("imgpath",imagepathb.tostring()).commit();                    

  }
```

i want to store this string array in shared preference when result received in `onActivityResult`. But I don't know how its work for multiple syntax in `loop`.
Any one can store this string array in shared preference for me. thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by first syntax and second syntax??

Comment: @Clairvoyant i mean, this is first syntax `imagepathb.append(al[i]).append(",");` in for loop. and this is second syntax `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is image path : "+ imagepathb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`  when i  run only first string builder variable `imagepatb` can store value for tamperory, but toast can not display value of `imagepathb`

Comment: @Clairvoyant when i execute only `System.out.println(imagepathb);` or `Toast with imagepathb` variable output  toast message display perfect. but when try to save this string array with shared preference it display only toast and share preference variable remain null(as it is).

Comment: Put `sharedpreference` line outside after the loop.

Comment: @Clairvoyant i also have try this and it's display null toast mesage.

Comment: Can you edit your code and show me how you changed it

Comment: @Clairvoyant  i have edited my code. just put sharerpreference outside for loop.

Comment: If you make a toast outside of loop then can you see imagepathb data

Comment: @Clairvoyant No i can't see toast outside loop. imagepathb data display null.

Comment: If you put sharedpreference inside your loop it will override your data. And string builder in loop is also overriding that's why you are getting single data entry.

Comment: @Clairvoyant I try to save its outside try and catch but it's still null. Now I think, i should try with DB.

Comment: You need to put logic to save in sharedPreference first get data from shared prefernece and use a string builder to append the new data with old shared preference data in loop not outside of loop

Comment: @Clairvoyant yes i am trying this. thank you for take time for me.

Comment: @Clairvoyant Hey, i  have done this. with split. first get string from shared preference using `sheredpreference.getString("imagepathb","")` and save it in `String ab`. After this i have add split(";") like this `String[] array = ab.split(",");` and run with for loop and its display all image path.

Comment: That's what i have already told you to do and you have used split too

Comment: I am here to help, thats it.

Comment: @Clairvoyant can you help me [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961325/how-to-update-first-and-second-page-view-in-view-pager).?

Answer (score 1):

First, if all the strings in your ArrayList are known to be unique (i.e. no duplicates), you can convert your *ArrayList* to a *Set* and store it, using the **putStringSet()** method:

```
sharedpreferences.edit().putStringSet("imgpath", new HashSet<String>(a)).commit();
```

when load, you can convert it back to *ArrayList*:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = 
      new ArrayList<>(sharedpreferences.getStringSet("imgpath", new HashSet<String>()));
```

another approach is to store several values with different names:

```
Edit edit = sharedpreferences.edit();
int cnt = 0;
for (String s : a) 
   edit.putString("imgpath_" + (cnt++), s);
while (sharedpreferences.getString("imgpath_" + cnt, null) != null) {
  edit.remove("imgpath_" + cnt); // delete all extra values from previous save time;
  cnt++;
}
edit.commit();
```

when loading you have to check until you get a null value;

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
for(int cnt = 0;; cnt++) {
   String s = sharedpreferences.getString("imgpath_" + cnt, null);
   if (s == null) break;
   a.add(s);
}
```

And for last, you can store it comma separated:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : a) {
    is (sb.length() > 0) sb.append(',');
   sb.append(s);
}
sharedpreferences.edit().putString("imgpath",sb.tostring()).commit();
```

When loading, you can use String.split to get array back

```
String[] al = sharedPreferences.getString("imgpath", "").split(',');
```

Comment: @peter Just one things you missed in first code. you don's save it with `commit();` without commit() it is work like only simple variable .

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is save it in database, the shared preferences is good to save variables of user conexion (users, passwords,...), initial variables, etc... But no to save array list, it's not a good programming practice! I know too you can't save array list as array list but if as Sets, you can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences).

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

Comment: @peter can you tell me how can i convert array-list to `set<string>`.? Because i am passing array-list in first activity.

Comment: Click in the hyperlink (post word) if you want to see the post, and if you want to pass array list from activity to another one then you need to find documentation about bundles!

Comment: @peter can you help me [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961325/how-to-update-first-and-second-page-view-in-view-pager)